# Как сделать в html так, чтобы при нажатии на флеш-элемент открывалась другая страница

Tags: html, flash, swf

На свой сайт ставлю флеш карту региона, в ней прописана ссылка, которая должна открываться при нажатии на карту. Прописал код, чтобы выставить на сайт.

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
        data="http://kcpmss.ucoz.ru/map-super.swf" width="600" height="400">
    <param name="movie" value="http://kcpmss.ucoz.ru/map-super.swf" />
</object>
```

Карта появляется, но вот при нажатии на неё никуда та ссылка не ведет. Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на карту открывалась вот эта ссылка:
`http://titf-info.jimdo.com/место-жительства/` ?

Answer (score 1):

Ссылка, прописанная во флешке не рабочая, адрес сайта, на который она ссылается не действителен. Сама флешка - конечный, закрытый от вмешательства продукт, изменить нерабочую ссылку у вас не получится (без доступа к исходным файлам этой флеш карты). Код, который вы привели, никакого отношения к содержимому флешки не имеет и никак на её внутривенную работу не влияет. Если это сложно понять, то я попробую на житейском примере объяснить. Представьте, что html - ваш автомобиль, а вы, его владелец, являетесь флеш картой Алтайского края. Вы садитесь в свой автомобиль и вдруг ваши руки отнялись. Вы бежите к врачу и спрашиваете: "- Доктор! Что мне поменять в своем автомобиле, а то у меня руки парализовало?" Врач в шоке, медсестра в обмороке... Автомобиль никакого отношения к вашим парализованным рукам не имеет. Т.е. html код никакого отношения к флешке не имеет.